# given to people in contact with the infected and their contacts

Tags: grammar

> Experimental vaccine can now be deployed to the epicenter of an
>   outbreak, **given** to people in contact with the infected and their
>   contacts.

Why did the author use "given" here? Is it a form of reduction?

Source: http://transcripts.cnn.com/TRANSCRIPTS/1806/01/sn.01.html

Comment: I'm not certain where you're struggling on this - People who have been in contact with the infection are given the vaccine. If it's pills, that may literally mean 'handed to them'. If it's an injection, it will be administered by a professional.

Comment: Thank you. I didn't understand about the use of "given" here. Is it participle? Do you mean the following is the complete sentence? Experimental vaccine can now be deployed to the epicenter of an outbreak, (the vaccine can be )given to people in contact with the infected and their contacts.

Comment: Yes, it's complete without the parenthetical addition. With it, it would better be broken into 2 sentences. At its bare minimum, the sentence is "Vaccine can be deployed, given to people." in effect, it is 'deployed' by being taken to the correct area, then given to people in need.

Comment: The sentence is not grammatical.  It's either a reduction, omitting certain words like "the" or "and", or the source is not a native speaker.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Experimental vaccine

  can now be

        deployed to the epicenter of an outbreak
        and
        given to people in contact with the infected and their contacts
```

can be deployed ... and ... (can be) given

> Experimental vaccine can be given to people ...

is a passive construction, where **given** is the past participle.  The same is true with **deployed**.

Comment: Thank you @Tᴚoɯɐuo. But, there is not a coordinator "and" here.

Comment: @samsam: And that missing **and** is what is ungrammatical about the sentence you posted.  The link to the transcript does not work for me, BTW.

Comment: Thank you. Here is the link : http://transcripts.cnn.com/TRANSCRIPTS/1806/01/sn.01.html

Comment: @samsam: OK, I got to the article. The piece is structured like a "bulleted list", though there are no bullet icons (*isolate patients...trace contacts...suit up...administer vaccines*).  The phrases are therefore *asyndetic* in a way that does not typically occur in normal prose or speech, with **and** omitted between those two participle clauses.

Comment: The writing is meant to be especially terse, like a list of things to be done.